# AndroidStudio - Firebase - Python connection is possible?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an Android app. In it I have to access to Python as I use the Matplotlib module. I want the logic to be like this:

1. The user inputs personalized data in the Android app
2. The data is sent to the Python script where the Matplotlib module is located
3. The image produced by Matplotlib module is fetched in Android Studio where is represented using Jetpack Compose.

My question is, can I do this using Firebase in order for it to be fast and efficient?

Comment: Sounds possible to me.  You should give it a try, then post again if something specific doesn't work the way you expect.  You'll likely end up writing a lot of code, both frontend and backend, in order to complete the loop between all these requirements.